# Url path in ExpressJS + NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have build an application with NodeJs + ExpressJs.
I have file jquery in folder js of public, ex:

```
http://192.168.2.129:7878/javascripts/jquery.min.js
```

But how can I config setting Express to get this file jquery when i get this url

```
http://192.168.2.129:7878/1111/javascripts/jquery.min.js
```

Answer (score 3):

From [documentation](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html), to add relative 'virtual' path you write following code:

```
app.use('/1111', express.static('public'));
```